# Regex before form submit with Rails and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, regex

How can I do form validation on an AJAX form that I have?  As it stands right now, I've made a customer jQuery validator to check for a valid IP address, but it seems that the validation is only happening on initial page load or when I refresh the page, which is totally wrong.

**assets/javascripts/tools.js**

```js
//Validation
jQuery.validator.addMethod('validIP', function(value) {
    var split = value.split('.');
    if (split.length != 4)
        return false;

    for (var i=0; i<split.length; i++) {
        var s = split[i];
        if (s.length==0 || isNaN(s) || s<0 || s>255)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}, alert('Invalid IP Address'));

$(".form_ip").validate({
  rules: {
   ip: {
          validIP: true
          }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**views/tools/ping.js.erb**

```js
$(".output").html("<%= j (@results) %>");
```

**views/tools/forms/_ping.html.erb**

```html
<%= form_tag ping_tool_path(1), role: "form", class: "form-inline form_ip", name: "ping-form", method: "post", remote: true do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :ip, params[:ip], class: "form-control" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Ping", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

as I don't know ruby, I'll try to answer about the client side.
Did you try to validate the form on button click?
For instance, with such a similar code?

```
<form class="form-inline form_ip" name="ping-form" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="ip" class="form-control">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="$('.form_ip').validate(...)">
```

Comment: tried that, still pops up the validate alert on page load.

Comment: that's because you write it directly into a <script> block.

Try to wrapper it into a function and run the function on the click